# Phonegap Error + Error: Cannot find module 'q'

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Trying to build phonegap app but strange error :-

```
user@ubuntu:~/Projects/PhoneGap/testapp$ phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...
Running command: /home/user/Projects/PhoneGap/testapp/platforms/android/cordova/build 

module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'q'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Projects/PhoneGap/testapp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/spawn.js:23:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

cordova -v => 5.3.3

wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"}

Please suggest something .. Thanks

Comment: cordova CLI version? cordova android version?

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: You executed "phonegap build android", which is the phonegap CLI version? And the cordova android version? (cordova platform list)

Answer (score 24):

I was struggling with same issue and finally figure out `npm install q --save` helps me.

Comment: Just did this as of today - 29/04/2019

Comment: same today 10/05/2020

Comment: I did a fresh clone of my repository and out of nowhere "cordova plugin remove someplugin" gave me this error.  Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue because my cordova android version was deprecated. Upgrade with

```
cordova platform update android
```

as described here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide/platforms/android/upgrading.html

Answer (score 3):

**This worked for me:**

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@7.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to do an `npm i .` when something is missing in node-like projects.

Missing 'q' is a sign that there is no node_modules folder at all generated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds odd, but uninstall and re-install latest version of NPM.